# How to setup Github Actions for Angular workspace?

Tags: angular, github-actions, firebase-hosting, angular-workspace-configuration

I have an angular workspace with 3 projects (all hosted on firebase)

```
my-workspace
 |-project1
 |-project2
 `-project3
```

Setting up github actions to build & deploy for angular apps is easy.

But how can I setup actions for projects in a workspace?

For example, when I push changes for project1, how can I build and deploy to project1 hosting only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a github actions workflow for each project, each with a trigger like the following:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'project1/**'
```

Then simply deploy the project that has changed.

Comment: Thank you! 

For anyone who is wondering how to trigger a workflow to "Deploy on staging on PR" you can set the path for each project in a simillar way.
```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
    paths:
      - project1/**'
```